# Validating a record to see if it only contains digits

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am validating VAT codes. The codes include GB in front of them but i would like to not include that and see if the rest of the vat code only includes numbers.

```
select KUNNR,VAT_CODE,REPLACE(VAT_CODE,'GB',''),
       CASE WHEN REPLACE(VAT_CODE,'GB','') LIKE '%[^0-9]%'   THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as VAT_MATCH
FROM  CUSTOMER_TBL;

"customer"  "VAT"           "REPLACE(VAT,'GB','')"  "VAT_MATCH"
"0063591544"    "GB111111111"   "111111111"           "No"
```

Comment: the DBMS is an sql sever

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @CUSTOMER_TBL TABLE (VAT_CODE VARCHAR(36));
INSERT @CUSTOMER_TBL VALUES ('GB123111GB'),('GB9999111'),('GBB9999111'),('GGB7777222'),
                            ('553399444'),('GB22223366'),('GB22223366X')

-- solution
SELECT t.VAT_CODE, VAT_MATCH = IIF(f.H = 'GB' AND PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',f.B) = 0,'Yes','No')
FROM        @CUSTOMER_TBL AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (SUBSTRING(t.VAT_CODE,1,2),SUBSTRING(t.VAT_CODE,3,8000))) AS f(H,B);

/* For pre-2012 systems:
   VAT_MATCH = CASE WHEN f.H = 'GB' AND PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',f.B) = 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END */;
```

**Results**

```
VAT_CODE                             VAT_MATCH
------------------------------------ ---------
GB123111GB                           No
GB9999111                            Yes
GBB9999111                           No
GGB7777222                           No
553399444                            No
GB22223366                           Yes
GB22223366X                          No
```